# Vehicle Routing Problem with Two fleets

Tags: gurobi, vehicle-routing, gurobipy

Based on the suggestion in the comment below. I edited my model by removing $w$. Here is the context:
I'm dealing with the CVRP with two heterogeneous fleets with the following capacities $q_1$ and $q_2$. I'm using the model based on flow. I tried to sepearate constraints for each type of fleet but the result is a disconnected route. Thus, the following model consists in combining the constaints. When $x_1(i,j)=0$ then $x_2(i,j)=1$ and when $x_1(i,j)=1$ then $x_2(i,j)=0$. For the last constraint on capacity, I define $CL$ the set of customers where demand doesn't exceed $q_2$.

$\min \sum_{i \in N, j \in N} {c_1(i,j)*x_1(i,j) + c_2(i,j)*x_2(i,j)}$

$\sum_{j \in C} x_1(0,j) <= n$

$\sum_{j \in C} x_2(0,j) <= m$

$\sum_{i \in C} x_1(i,0) <= n$

$\sum_{i \in C} x_2(i,0) <= m$

$\sum_{i \in N} x_1(i,j) + x_2(i,j) = 1 \quad \forall j \in C$

$\sum_{i \in N} x_1(i,j) - x_1(j,i) = 0 \quad \forall j \in C$

$\sum_{i \in N} x_2(i,j) - x_2(j,i) = 0 \quad \forall j \in C$

$y(j) + z(j) <= y(i) + z(i) -d_j*(x_1(i,j) + x_2(i,j)) + M*(1-(x_1(i,j) + x_2(i,j)) \quad \forall i \in C, j \in C$

$ 0 <= y(i) <= q_1 - d_i \quad \forall i \in C$

$ 0 <= z(i) <= q_2 - d_i \quad \forall i \in CL$

I run the code on the following data ($q_1=35$ and $q_2=15$):

```
    lat  long  demand
0  30.0  40.0       0
1  37.0  52.0      19
2  49.0  49.0      30
3  52.0  64.0      16
4  31.0  62.0      23
5  52.0  33.0      11
```

The solution is wrong since the demand of the customer 4 is 23 >= q_2 = 15:
$x_1 = [(0, 2), (2, 5), (1, 3), (3, 0), (5, 0), (0, 1)]
x_2 = [(4, 0), (0, 4)]$

```
y[1] = 16.0
y[2] = 0.0
y[3] = 0.0
y[4] = 0.0
y[5] = 0.0
z[1] = 7.615501519756847
z[2] = 11.0
z[3] = 7.615501519756847
z[4] = 0.7720364741641355
z[5] = 0.0
```

I have doubt in the constraint 8 that assure the flow. When I seperate this type of constraint, I got disconnected routes. Someone can help me in this model? I'm not sure what is wrong in my model. Does anyone have any idea?
Thank you

Comment: Wouldn't $\omega$ have indices $i,j$?

Comment: $w$ depends on $x1$ and $x2$. I can’t figure out why should it have indices i,j?

Comment: Otherwise $w$ will keep changing with $i,j$ pair. Also if you are restricting $x1+x2=1$ for pairs of edges you may not need $w$ as it seems to be $w=x1+x2$

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. In fact, I remove $w$ from the model described above (I edited my post). I run it the model but the solution that I get is wrong. I still miss something in my model. What should I do to respect the constraint of customers demand (I put the numerical details in my post above).

Comment: you are bounding $z_4 in [0,15-23]$ or $[15-23,0]$?

Comment: one more thing no need for separate counters like $y,z$. Only one type will do say $0 \le y_i \le \max \{ q1-d_i,q2-d_i \}$

Comment: Cross-posted: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461854/two-index-formulation-for-capacited-vehicle-routing

Answer (score 1):

Also since depot $0$ is not part of $C$ so for arcs$(0,4),(4,0)$ constraint 8 isn't applicable.
Together with bounds on counters $y$ or $z$ the solver finds $x_1$ more feasible so long it meets constraints
If you want second type of vehicles to cover more routes try increasing the capacity $q_2$ or reducing demand at the customer nodes.

In case you'd want vehicle to serve a customer node only if $q_2 \le d_i$ then you can add a constraint
$q^k (\sum_jx_{j,i}^k - 1) \le d_i - q^k \quad \forall k=1,2 \ \ \forall i \in C$

Or for depot specific constraint since constraint (8) is taking care
$q^k (x_{0,i}^k+x_{i,0}^k - 1) \le d_i -q^k \quad \forall k=1,2 \ \ \forall i \in C$

Comment: It makes sense to only keep one variable representing the flow after leaving the customer $i$. Let's assume $y$. Then, the constraint (8) become:  $y_j<=y_i-d_j(x_1(i,j)+x_2(i,j)) - M*(1- (x_1(i,j)+x_2(i,j)))$ where $M = max{q1,q2}$ and $0<=y_i<=max{q1-d_i,q2-d_i}$.  The solution that I get is: 
$x_1= [(4, 0), (3, 1), (5, 4), (0, 5), (1, 0), (0, 3)]$ and $x_2=[(0, 2), (2, 0)]$ I suppose that the customer $2$ must not served by the fleet 2 since $d_2=30 > q_2=15$. The problem that my model did not state this assumption.

Comment: @MAYA, look constraint 8 excludes $0$ as your set $C$ doesn't include $0$. right? As for the rest where there's a selected edge from other customers $(3,1)$ the solver finds $q_1$ more feasible.

Comment: Yes, the constraint 8 includes customers since $y_i$ Is the load after visiting customer $i$. But for (0,2) is not correct to belong to the solution x_2. The latter concerns trucks with $q_2=15$ and demand for the customer 2 is 30.

Comment: Yes but that capacity/demand isn't appearing in any of the constraints. Only constraint that restricts it (8) skips it as it doesn't include node $0$. So solver is happy to assign edge $(0,2) & (2,0)$

Comment: You are right. Should I keep $y$ and $z$ to consider the case where $d_i > q$ then $0<=zi<=q_2_d_i$ in this case it will be negative then zi will equal to 0.  But this variable concerns the customer i

Comment: You can try the constraint in the answer edited above.

Comment: The constraint uses  a décision variable with three indexes. However my model uses two index with auxiliary variable y to assure the load of each vehicle. In this sense, I have to consider the case where $q <d$. Could you help me to formalise it correctly?

Comment: @MAYA, that $k$ is your $1,2$ representing 2 types of fleet. You can use $x1, x2$ as well.

Comment: I tried the following constraint to not serve the customer $i$ when $q_2<d_i$:
$q_2*(\sum_{j \in N} x_{j,i}−1)≤q_2 - d_i ∀i∈C$. I have a violated constraint when $d_i=31 and q_2=15$: $15*(x_06+x_60)<-1$ The sum of binaries variables can not be negative. In this cas, $x_06$ and $x_60 = 0$. Thank you for your help

Comment: The case when $q<<d$ the inequality is no more validated